# Huawei App Review rejected my application due to some regions appear as country

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

My application got rejected in app review by Huawei App Gallery, due to some regions appear as country.
Below is the Error
We quote, "[Description]: We found that it does not display correctly when selecting a country in the purchase section in your app (for example, some of the regions should not be shown as countries)"

We are using a website link and display Countrylist as a web view within the app. It's developed that way to help our members easily navigate and register to our program. The website is directed from an external website that we do not have any control or access.

Answer (score 2):

For releasing APP in App Gallery you need to modify countries label to Country/Region as Hong Kong and Macau cannot be presented as countries on the area code page.

You can check below reference link about common Reasons of Rejecting Apps in App Gallery:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/30208

[image]